# Touch Listener on multiple image views in a single Activity

Tags: android, android-imageview, multi-touch

I want to dynamically add multiple imageViews on my activity and then handle touch events on each imageView individually. I am able to do this with single imageView like this:

This is the activity:

```
public class Touch extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
private static final String TAG = "Touch";
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
 private PointF start = new PointF();
 private PointF mid = new PointF();
 private float oldDist = 1f;

// We can be in one of these 3 states
static final int NONE = 0; 
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    view.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)

{
    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
    // Dump touch event to log
    dumpEvent(event);

    // Handle touch events here... 
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
    { 

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
        start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
        Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG" );
        mode = DRAG;
        break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        mode = NONE;
        Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE" );
        break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (mode == DRAG) {
        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
        matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
        event.getY() - start.y);
        }

        else if (mode == ZOOM) {
            float newDist = spacing(event);
            Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
            if (newDist > 10f) {
            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            float scale = newDist / oldDist;
            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
            }
            }
        break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            oldDist = spacing(event);
            Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
            if (oldDist > 10f) {
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            midPoint(mid, event);
            mode = ZOOM;
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM" );
            }
            break;
    }

    view.setImageMatrix(matrix); 
    return true; // indicate event was handled
}

/** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",
            "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int action = event.getAction();
    int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
    if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
            || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
        sb.append("(pid ").append(
                action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
        sb.append(")");
    }
    sb.append("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
        sb.append("#").append(i);
        sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
        sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
        sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
        if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
            sb.append(";");
    }
    sb.append("]");
    Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
}

private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }
```

}

This is the main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:src="@drawable/basketball"
android:scaleType="matrix"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

But if i add another image below it and make it's width and height to "wrap_content" then it just moves in the specified area. Below is the link of image of result that i get when i try to add multiple touch events:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vymbsv88fqm26xx/SC20121118-231359.png

Comment: The positioning of the ImageViews has nothing to do with the touch events.

Comment: If the image view is "fill_parent" then it is working fine, but this way it captures the whole screen, and another image can not be added. And if i make it "wrap_content" then a boundary is created to move the image, wrt to the size of each image.

Comment: I want to move and zoom multiple image views on a single activity (images should be able to move anywhere on the screen). This is what i  want to achieve, any help in achieving this would be appreciated

Comment: Tahreem , have you got solution for this problem. I am also facing the same.

Comment: Check this one out https://github.com/Grishu/MYDroid...Its showing touch event on multiple images

Answer (score 0):

I hope my below code help you solve your problem. In this code I am creating an array of ImageViews using for loop. Depending on the Image touched I add to a TextView a number corresponding to the image clicked.

```
mImages= new ImageView[numImage];
    for (int i=0; i <numImage; i++) {
        String imgID = "imageNum" + (i+1);
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imgID, "id", getActivity().getPackageName());
        mImages[i] = view.findViewById(resID);


        mImages[i].setOnTouchListener(new ImageView.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent) {




                int msg=-1;
                //v.getId() will give you the image id
                switch(v.getId()){
                    case R.id.imageNum1:
                        if(v.getPivotX()==motionEvent.getX() && v.getPivotY()==motionEvent.getY()) {
                            msg = 1;
                        }
                        break;
                    case R.id.imageNum2:
                        msg=2;
                        break;
                    case R.id.imageNum3:
                        msg=3;
                        break;
                    case R.id.imageNum4:
                        msg=4;
                        break;
                    case R.id.imageNum5:
                        msg=5;
                        break;
                    case R.id.imageNum6:
                        msg=6;
                        break;
                    case R.id.imageNum7:
                        msg=7;
                        break;
                    case R.id.imageNum8:
                        msg=8;
                        break;
                    case R.id.imageNum9:
                        msg=9;
                        break;


                }//switch

                if(msg!=-1)
                usertextView.setText(usertextView.getText().toString()+msg);

        return true;
            }//onTouch
        });//setOnTouchlistener



    }//for
```